# Why does the one-time pad not imply $P \not= NP$?

Tags: one-time-pad, one-way-function

I apologize that this is a rather trivial question, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.  If the one-time pad is unconditionally secure and impossible to crack (with just ciphertext), why does this not imply $P \not= NP$?  If not the one-time pad, what properties would a cryptographic system need to exhibit in order to imply $P \not= NP$?

Comment: What properties?  Well, one possibility would be that a decision problem associated with the cryptographic system be provably within NP, and provably not within P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one time pad is secure regardless of complexity. When you have a ciphertext all plaintexts are equally likely and you have no way to verify a guess. Even an attacker which enumerates all possible keys will not learn anything he didn't know already. Thus it doesn't have anything to do with complexity.

A one way function on the other hand implies $P \ne NP$. Any function which is easy to compute in one direction but hard to find a pre image. Since finding a preimage of a polynomial time function is in $NP$.

Note it is possible that no one way functions exist and and still $P$ does not equal $NP$.

A one time pad is not a one way function. It is trivial to find a preimage We can find as many preimages as we want we can't tell them apart.

Comment: "Since finding a preimage of a polynomial time function is in NP." Strictly speaking that's not true, since a search problem cannot be in NP. The corresponding decision problem is in NP though.

Comment: Shouldn't $a = b\ mod\ p$ be a one way function? Because, for any $a$ then $b = k \cdot p + a$.

Comment: @shumy $a=b \bmod p$ is clearly not a OWF, since a itself is a preimage that's trivial to find.

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by it is easy to compute a preimage.  Do you mean it is easy because we just pick a random key and random message and they look the same?

Comment: If we look at the encryption as a function it's input is both message and key, and for any cipher text we can produce any number of plaintext,key pairs to match the ciphertext.

Comment: @MeirMaor ok, but if it was the case that such "preimages" could only be found with negligible probability then it would be a one-way function?

Comment: Yes. Think of a cryptographic hash function. It is trivial to calculate it in the forward direction e.g h(x)=y but given y we have no reasonable way of finding a preimage leading to it. We can brute force all possible values to find one, and with some negligble probability we will find a preimage in our first few guesses.

Comment: @MeirMaor but what if you added a random element to the one time pad so that a pseudo inverse could only be found with negligible probability?  Are one way functions that prove P does not equal NP deterministic so that the same input gives the same ciphertext every time?

Comment: The complexity class P is defined on a determinstic touring machine. If a function isn't determinstic the idea of preimage isn't even clearly defined.