# Question regarding a subset of p=?np

Tags: one-time-pad

We consider a language that is $\{0,1\}^n$. We consider three variables $A$, $B$ and $K$ part of that language. A and K are generated through true random generator.

We consider not two as is traditional but three Turing machines:

-The encrypter. This takes as input a key $K$ and a value $A$. This output $B$ in polynomial time in the worst case.

-The decrypter. This takes as input $B$ and output $A$. It can call the checker.

-The checker. This takes as input $I$ and $B$ and output whether $I == A$. This computation is in polynomial time in the worst case.

---

For the following, we shall consider these instantiations of the Turing machine:

-The encrypter compute $A\text{ XOR }K = B$. This can be computed in linear time in the worst case.

-The decrypter can be anything. It can make as many calls as needed on the checker.

-The checker compute $(I\text{ XOR }K) == B$. This can be computed in linear time in the worst case.

---

Now that we have the definitions, let's discuss the problem.

Claim : For this decrypter and checker there is no decrypter that is polynomial in times in the worst case.

Proof:
As $A$, $B$ and $K$ are independent of one another, having access to $B$ reveal no information on $A$ (one-time pad has perfect secrecy, see Shannon work on the subject). Therefore, the decrypter must call the checker to get information on $A$.

As each call to the checker only confirm whether the proposed $I$ is $A$ or not, they do not reveal any more information about $A$ than $A$ being in the subset $\{\text{all possible }A\}$ minus $\{\text{all attempted }I\}$. This is again because of the one-time pad field structure, as any $I!=A$ is independent of $A$.

From this the only way for the decrypter to find $A$ is try various $I$ with the checker (as it's the only way for it to uncover information about $A$) until they find an $I$ such as $I==A$ (for which the checker returns true). In the worst case, this is $2^n$ calls to the checker, which is non polynomial in times.

---

We can extend this result in such a way that:

-The encrypter is a random permutation f such as f(A) = B. The permutation is secret.

-The decrypter can be anything. It can make as many calls as needed on the checker.

-The checker verify I==A.

Because the permutation is random, every potential I is independent of A if I!=A.

---

What is the issue in my reasoning here?

PS: I hesitated between here and the math stack exchange. Please tell me if I should post this question on there instead. I posted here because this subset of the p=np problem is immediately relevant to cryptography.

Comment: you may want to use mathjax to format your question.

Comment: @kodlu I have reformatted the question (mathjax and spacing issues). My apologies.

Comment: The problem is this; the permutation is not polynomial time!

Comment: @kelalaka Indeed, this does break the extension. Thank you.

Comment: @kelalaka, you should enter that as an answer

Comment: @kodlu It doesn't answer the question regarding the one-times pad issue. The random permutation could be computed in exponential times (but it could also be computed in polynomial times as with the one times pad example).

Comment: @kelalaka For one times pad, the permutation can be stored on a bit more than n characters (whetever characters are used to indicate a xor).

edit: Keygen rely upon a TRNG? If anything that rely on a TRNG is not part of p=?np, nothing in cryptography is part of the problem.

Comment: Let me re-read...

Comment: Applying permutation, if I got it correctly, worsens the OTP since permutation in this manner cannot represent all cases as OTP. The decryptor needs only ask for those cases

Comment: @kelalaka I think I badly expressed myself then (I am ESL). The permutation here is the OTP (there are no other permutations).

I tried extending it to any permutation but it doesn't hold as you have demonstrated.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what the language is here. I'm thinking of it like this: it is the set of strings B equipped with the checker algorithm such that the checker algorithm outputs 1 for some I. Then I believe it is not in NP. As you have stated, the turing machine M who only knows B and the checker algorithm runs in exponential time. Would this be a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Lev It's not a decidability problem at all.

You could change it into one (for exemple by verifying whether the first z bits are zero).

Edit: My understand of the p=np problem applied to cryptography is that if p=np, it would be possible to uncover the key/plaintext is polynomial times.
If this is indeed not in np, cryptography should be able to be resistant even if p=np.

Comment: @Lev I am not sure what you meant regarding language. The language is the same for A, B and K ($\{0, 1\}^n$). A simple binary array of length n in other terms.

Comment: I suggest you look at the definition of NP as it's clear there is some confusiom. It is a class of decision problems. If your language was just all binary strings of length n then you could decide if a string was in the language by checking it's length. Which is in P. But that completely defeats the purpose of your whole scheme.

Comment: This scheme is a one time pad. One time pads offer perfect secrecy. Even if P=NP it would be unaffected.

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/77983/why-does-the-one-time-pad-not-imply-p-not-np

Comment: @Lev This is why I added the checker. It makes it solvable.

I have proposed a way to make it into a decision problem.
> for exemple by verifying whether the first z bits are zero

Comment: The first z bits of what?

Comment: If you take the language of binary strings of length n where the first z bits are zero, the language is in P and not really meaningful.